# jQuery AJAX json error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Here is my JSON object.

```
{
        "verbs" : [
        "process",
        "refine",
        "define"
        ],
        "adjectives" : [
        "process",
        "audio",
        "language"
        ],
        "subjects" : [
        "process",
        "development",
        "technique"    
            ]
}
```

Here is my attempt to access and process the data via the jQuery AJAX method.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "js/tsbtw-object.js",
    success : function(data, statusText){

        var verbArray = data.verbs;

        for(var i = 0; i<verbArray.length; i++){

            var verbTime = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);

            jQuery("#verb-content").fadeOut(verbTime, function(){
                (this).text(verbArray[i]).fadeIn(verbTime);
            });
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(thrownError);
    }   
});
```

I am receiving two errors in the FireBug console.

invalid label
"verbs" : [\n

this.text is not a function
(this).text(verbArray[j]).fadeIn(verbTime);\n

I was up fairly late trying to puzzle this out, and thought I would kick it out the community for insight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `$(this).text` instead of `(this).text`. Also note that as you are in an ajax callback `this` points to the options for the ajax request, so the `text` function might not be defined. Instead you could try with:

```
var _this = this;
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "js/tsbtw-object.js",
    success : function(data, statusText){
        var verbArray = data.verbs;
        for(var i = 0; i<verbArray.length; i++){
            var verbTime = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
            jQuery("#verb-content").fadeOut(verbTime, function(){
                    $(_this).text(verbArray[i]).fadeIn(verbTime);
            });
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(thrownError);
    }   
});
```

Comment: no, in this case, $(this) points to $('#verb-content') , not to the options of the ajax request.