# alert response from server via jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here's the response:

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

how can i display an alert box with the value of `"Message"`.
This has not worked for me:

```
error: function (data) { alert(data[0]); }
```

or

```
error: function (data) { alert(data.Message); }
```

Comment: I recommend you console.log(data) and look what you actually get at this place

Comment: no idea why i didnt even try that. thanks I can use .status to return the 401 that I needed.

Comment: [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248730/jquery-ajax-json-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
error: function(header, status, exception) {
    alert(exception.Message);
}
```

taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Answer (score 1):

if you has got the data as string,you can use:

```
var msg = jQuery.parseJSON(data); alert(msg.Message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can go with as Christian suggests or use

```
function (response) {
var error = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
alert('Sorry, an error occurred. Please contact support. The error was: ' + error.Message);
}
});
```